# CATIA VBA Connection with Excel

Tags: vba, catia

I wrote a piece of code in VBA of CATIA, using Selection object. I needed an access to a Excel file to get some value from it, so I ticked the library "Microsoft Excel Object Library", but whenever I do that, an error appear with the message "Run-time error '91. Object variable or With block variable not set" (see the image). Otherwise there is no problem[image]. I can't make out why? Any help would be appreciated, please!

Comment: Did you put Excel higher that Catia in the list of references?

Comment: @GSerg The Excel-related reference is under all of CATIA references which is available by default in VBA of CATIA

Comment: Declare your variables then. `Dim Selection As <whatever the type of Document.Selection is>`.

Comment: Guessing: `Dim Selection As CATIA.Document.Selection`  or `Dim Selection As CATIA.Selection`  (You are not currently Dimming it at all)

Comment: Try using variable names which are not the same as excel object names. 

Set oDoc = CATIA.ActiveDocument
Set oSel = oDoc.Selection 

oSel.SelectElement2(...)

Also, your code will throw that error also if there is no open document in CATIA.